# I am trying to get two calculation outputs from one input in javascript

Tags: javascript, input, output

I am creating this web calculator where I am trying to do two separate calculations from one output. There will be one input number (INPUT1) and I would like it to calculate INTPUT1/25 which produces OUTPUT1.

Then I would like to also calculate (INPUT1/25)/6 to pretty much show if the input was divided by 25 and then divided again by 6.

With my code, only one calculation displays at a time. Is there a way to produce two output calculations for one input number?

```
<form name="TESTING">
    <table border="1" width="600" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <h1>TESTING</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <th>
                <h3>INPUT</h3>
            </th>
            <th>
                <h3>OUTPUT</h3>
            </th>   
            <th>
                <h3>OUTPUT 2</h3>
            </th>  
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="INPUT1" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="OUTPUT1" id="output">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="OUTPUT2" id="output2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
        RESULT = (USERINPUT1/25);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = RESULT;
}

function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
        RESULT = ((USERINPUT1/25)/6);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT2.value = RESULT;
}
</script>
```

Comment: you cant have two functions named the same, the first one just gets overwritten by the second one. Change the name of one of your functions.

Comment: Why don't you just add `document.TESTING.OUTPUT2.value = RESULT/6` to your `calculate` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare multiple times a function expeting different results like that. i sugest you to rename then as different functions and then call it with your calculate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
   test1(), test2();
}

function test1() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
        RESULT = (USERINPUT1/25);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = RESULT;
}

function test2() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
        RESULT = ((USERINPUT1/25)/6);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT2.value = RESULT;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, agreed with @Marvin, you cannot define 2 functions with the same name.You can add both output functions in the same 'calculate' function like this:  
function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value;
        RESULT = (USERINPUT1/25);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = RESULT;
        RESULT1 = ((USERINPUT1/25)/6);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT2.value = RESULT1;
}